# Access all fields in Zapier Code Step

Tags: zapier

Is it possible to access all the fields from a previous step as a collection like json rather than having to explicitly setting each one in the input data?

Hope the screenshot illustrates the idea:
https://www.screencast.com/t/TTSmUqz2auq

The idea is I have a step that lookup responses in a google form and I wish to parse the result to display all the Questions and Answer into an email.

Hope this is possible

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team. Unfortunately, what I believe you're describing right now isn't possible. Usually this works fine since users only map a few values. The worst case is when you want every value, which it sounds like you're facing. It would be cool to map all of them. I can pass that along to the team! In the meantime, you'll have to click everything you're going use in the code step.

If you really don't want to create a bunch of variables, but you could map them all into a single input and separate them with a separator like `|`, which (as long as it doesn't show up in the data), it's easy to split in the code step.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to create an additional field in the output object that is a JSON string of the output. In a Python code step, it would look like

```python
import json

output = {'id': 123, 'hello': 'world'}
output['allfields'] = json.dumps(output)
```

or for returning a list

```python
import json

output = [{'id': 123, 'hello': 'world'},{'id': 456, 'bye': 'world'}]
for x in output:
    x['allfields'] = json.dumps(output[output.index(x)])
```

Now you have the individual value to use in steps as well as ALL the values to use in a code step (simply convert them from JSON). The same strategy holds for Javascript as well (I simply work in Python).

**Zapier Result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fields are accessible in an object called `input_data` by default. So a very simplistic way of grabbing a value (in Python) would be like:

```
my_variable = input_data['actual_field_name_from_previous_step']
```

This differs from explicitly naming the the field with Input Data (optional). Which as you know, is accessed like so:

```
my_variable = input['your_label_for_field_from_previous_step']
```

Here's the process description in [Zapier docs](https://zapier.com/help/create/code-webhooks/python-code-examples-in-zaps).

Hope this helps.